# Where is the argument?

Tags: programming

I have this code on my hard disk and now I would like to understand it. Firstly I would like to know if this code is correct and logic or if there is another way to do the same thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand*\macro[2][]{%
  Option : #1\par % print the option in #1
  \let\y #2 % to keep 
\begingroup
  \catcode`\(=1
  \catcode`\)=2
  \macrobis
}
\newcommand*\macrobis[1]{%
\endgroup
\scantokens{\def\temp{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\def\fct{x*x}

\macro[op]{\fct}(exp(1))

\FPeval\x{\temp}%
\FPeval\img{\y}%
x = \x\ donne  y = \img

\end{document}
```

`\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are here, I suppose, because the code changes the catcodes but tha call of macrobis is very strange. Where is the argument ?
Can someone explain this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see one command at a time:

```
\newcommand*\macro[2][]{%
  Option : #1\par % print the option in #1
  \let\y #2 % to keep 
\begingroup
  \catcode`\(=1
  \catcode`\)=2
  \macrobis
}
```

`\macro` has one optional argument (default empty) and a mandatory one. It assumes that the mandatory argument is *one* token, as it does `\let\y#2` (but will leave a space in the input stream). Then it opens a group where it sets `(` and `)` as delimiters just like `{` and `}`; after this it calls `\macrobis`.

```
\newcommand*\macrobis[1]{%
\endgroup
\scantokens{\def\temp{#1}}}
```

`\macrobis` gathers its argument considering `(` and `)` as braces. Then it ends the group, so `(` and `)` return to their previous status and defines `\temp` to expand to `#1` but inside `\scantokens` so the possible `(` and `)` characters in `#1` will be rescanned in this setting where they are not delimiters any more.

What appears to be a parenthesized second mandatory argument to `\macro` is actually the argument to `\macrobis`, but this is not relevant from a user's point of view.

The point is to hide possible parentheses in that argument: if one defined

```
\newcommand*\macro[2][]{%
  Option : #1\par % print the option in #1
  \let\y #2 % to keep 
  \macrobis}
\def\macrobis(#1){\def\temp{#1}}
```

then an input such as `\macro[op]{\fct}(exp(1))` would interpret `exp(1` as the argument to `\macrobis`, which would be wrong.

Comment: This is magic !

Comment: @Altermundus A slick trick indeed!

Comment: There is no problem with the first  `(`but why it's the last `)` that is used like a brace ?

Comment: @Altermundus In order to gather the argument! In the example, when `\macrobis` is called, this is equivalent to write `{exp{1}}` so everything is balanced and the argument is `exp(1)` (TeX considers those as delimiters, but after `\scantokens` they return to be as normal).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I interpret it, macros (or control sequences) could be considered "replacements" for larger constructs (here "larger constructs" refers to the macro contents). As such, `\macro` gobbles `\macro[op]{\fct}` since it requires 2 arguments, does some magic, and replaces it with `\macrobis`. Still left in the input steam is `(exp(1))` with the category codes changed for `(` and `)` to group beginning and endings, respectively. So, effectively you're left with `\macrobis{exp(1)}`, which represents valid input for `\macrobis`, since it requires a single argument.

On a related note, consider the following. `\FPeval` is a macro that takes two arguments as is evident from `\show\FPeval`:

```
> \FPeval=macro:
#1#2->\FP@eval {#1}{#2}.
```

However, if you define

```
\newcommand{\myfunc}{\FPeval}
```

where `\myfunc` now takes no arguments, and use

```
\myfunc\x{\temp}%
\myfunc\img{\y}%
x = \x\ donne  y = \img
```

you'll get the same output, illustrating the idea behind replacement.

Comment: Good remark with `\newcommand{\myfunc}{\FPeval}`